# Is currying implemented using lambdas in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda, currying

Is following code right way to think about currying in Haskell. Following is an example of addition in haskell

```
f = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

In general is currying realized using lamdbas in functional programming?

Comment: Yes, in Haskell `f x y = ...` is defined to mean `f = \x -> \ y -> ...`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Currying is:

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument. It was introduced by Gottlob Frege, developed by Moses Schönfinkel, and further developed by Haskell Curry.

[source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

now you could argue that in Haskell there is **never** more than one argument to a function (you can of course have *tuples* - see below) - so in a sense **all** functions in Haskell are already *curried* (or can only be defined in such a way).

Of course there are [`curry`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry) and [`uncurry`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) - but those *act on tuples*:

```
curry                   :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y             =  f (x, y)
```

and I could argue that a tuple is just *one argument* too ;)

---

On a conceptual level you are of course right as augustss pointed out!

But sadly there are some problems ([see Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) for example) where this equality does not hold (if you don't add a type signature):

```
add x y = x + y === add = \x -> \y -> x + y
```

Comment: The equality holds just fine with the monomorphism restriction. You just have to give both functions type signatures.

Comment: @amalloy I probably should have mentioned this yes - but the OP did not and I just wanted to comment on the comment by augustss